# What Sugino crank is this?

Tags: crankset

I stumbled upon this image of a Sugino crank and it reminded me of the popular Ritchey Logic crank. Knowing that Sugino manufactured those Ritchey cranks I was wondering if Sugino also sold the same model under their own brand name. Does anybody have some insights on this specific model?

[image: Sugino crank]

[image: Ritchey Logic crank]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe those two are the same forging but I don't know the model for the version Sugino sold under their own name. There's a very similar one still in the lineup available new, the XD2 Compact Double arm set. It's not the same forging but is close.

Comment: isn't it the Sugino RD2, nath?

Comment: @Noise My recollection (only as someone who appreciates Sugino but isn't any kind of superfan) is the RD2 is a 130 crank only. The cranks in the OP's pictures are 110.

Comment: Of course, you're right. I did a little image search and I'm sure it's the fabulously named *Sugino Mighty Tour 2*